# Multi tenancy with Lock tables.. please vet my approach

Tags: c#, mysql

I am in the processes of building a multi tenant web app.

There may be times when there are multiple users updating the user tables and I have to maintain some sort of data integrity via locking and accounting for the latency in the web vs competition for the records.  Users must have a reasonable amount of time where they can be assure the documents will not change as they make changes. 10 minutes is the time I chose.

Instead of locking records in database tables,  I have a table of pseudo locks.  In order to modify a record the user must successfully insert and maintain a record in the LockTable  If the lock is successful the user will get the data if not they get an error and are told it is locked by another user. Maintaining the lock requires the user to do something to the document which will cause the browser to ask the server to update the lock at least every 10 minutes.  After 10 minutes another user can take the lock. When a user who has a lock submits an update or any other action the first thing that happens on the server is a check  to make sure they still have the lock

Documents are set up in the classic way with a header table and a details table.

Simplified Example:

Assume an order has a single OrderHeader record and multiple OrderDetails  records. The user has have received a part of the order and wants to update the order status and received quantities.

User sends request for a list of Orders from the server.
User selects document "27"

The browser sends a request to the server to lock and retrieve document "27".

On Server

```
GetOrderDocument(Document & user information)
{

   Insert into LockTable USER:=CurrentUser TABLE:=ORDERHEADER RECORD:=27 LockTime:=Now  

   if ( lock insert fails)  // document is already locked
   {
       GetLock TABLE:=ORDERHEADER RECORD:=27 // read the current lock
       if( Now - LockTime > 10 min) // if lock is older than 10 min
       {
            take over lock by changing USER: and Locktime
       }
       else
       {
            return message to browser "Document is locked by <user name>"
       }
   }
    /* user now has the lock*/
   Select document header& details  with  LockTime into a Json
   Return Json
}
```

on browser user makes changes presses save

browser

```
SaveData()
{
   collect data to update
   Set up ajax call and send update data and the LockTime last received from the server 
}
```

On Server

```
UpdateData(Changes, OldLockTime)
{
    Check DBLockTime in DB with  OldLockTime
    if ( DBLockTime == OldLockTime )   
    {
        Update LockTime with LockTime:=Now
    }
    else
    { 
      message="you have lost the document lock. changes not saved"
      return message
    }
    Update records as required
    return event status and new LockTime 
}
```

rinse and repeat.
When the user is done with the document a request is sent to the server to remove the LockTable record.  If this fails it can only last a max of 10 minutes.

This takes care of the latency issues of modifying documents over the web and ensures that a user has a reasonable amount of time to do their work but ensure that if the user walks away or their internet dies the records will become available.

Now I need to to throw some more stuff into the mix.

Sometimes the server needs to examine and update another record in a different table in addition to the main document. The record is a counter record which needs to be read and then incremented.  The server only needs this record for the time of the other document updates  but the read and update of this counter needs to be atomic with and in the same transaction as the main document.

What I do in that case is

On Server

```
UpdateData(Changes, OldLockTime)
{
    Check DBLockTime in DB with  OldLockTime
    if ( DBLockTime == OldLockTime )   
    {
        Update LockTime with LockTime:=Now
    }
    else
    { 
      message="you have lost the document lock. changes not saved"
      return message
    }
    set haveLock = false
    loop 10 times
         /* trying to insert new lock record in Locktable*/
        if( GetCounterRecordLock == false)
            sleep 1 second
        else
        {
            haveLock = true
            break out of loop.
        }
    endloop
    if ( haveLock == false)
      return error message indication update failure

    Start transaction

    read and update counter table.  

    Update main document records as required
    commit trans.
    delete CounterRecordLock from LockTable

    return event status and new LockTime 
}
```

I know the lock record stuff works very well. That has been tested to death.

My concern is with trying to get that second lock for the counter record.

Is trying to get it 10 times and waiting 1 second between attempts the correct approach? The thoughts of others is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be a little overbaked, though its hard to tell, usually you deal with these sort of things on the row level using concurrency checks

Comment: @TheGeneral.  Way back in the day I was an SAP developer.  In SAP you opened a document it was yours until you gave it up or your session timed out. That is what I based this on.  They also do not do actual database locks at all.  The locks are all done in a locking table in a manner similar to what I have described here. 

 My thoughts are that if a user is working on a document he needs to have it.  In the industry this is pointed at users are often  pulled away and interrupted.

Comment: Ahh i see where you a going with this, anyway maybe someone else can chime in